# How do I specify the bandwidth of a 2D Difference of Gaussian filter?

Tags: python, image, image-processing, filtering, gaussian

**This is more a question on theory of Gaussian filters, than specific coding question.**

I've got an implementation of a `2D D.O.G`. filter in python. I want to make noise masks at different spatial frequency bands e.g. `1-5 cpd`. To do this I first create a white noise array and then I will add the DOG filters to bandpass filter the noise across different spatial ranges.

Is there a way to explicitly define the bandwidth of a Difference of Gaussian filter from the parameters of each contributing Gaussian filter?

(**BONUS** Q's: Would it be possible to take a Fourier transform of each of these Gaussians and then view this as a spectrum of their individual bandwidths, and then DOG bandwidth? What would the units be in the Fourier space? How could I convert this into a spatial frequency scale? Sorry lots of questions)

Many thanks,

**NOTE:** I use the `conv2` function, rather than inbuilt python 2d convolutions, for speed (other applications).

```
import numpy as np
import math
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
from scipy.ndimage.filters import convolve

def Gaussian2D(GCenter, Gamp, Ggamma,Gconst): #new_theta > 0.4:
    """
    Produces a 2D Gaussian pulse    *EDITED BY WMBM

    Parameters
    ----------
    GCenter : int
            Centre point of Gaussian pulse
    Gamp : int
            Amplitude of Gaussian pulse
    Ggamma : int
            FWHM of Gaussian pulse
    Gconst : float
            Unkown parameter of density function

    Returns
    ----------
    GKernel : array_like
            Gaussian kernel
    """
    new_theta = math.sqrt(Gconst**-1)*Ggamma
    SizeHalf = np.int(math.floor(9*new_theta))
    [y, x] = np.meshgrid(np.arange(-SizeHalf,SizeHalf+1), np.arange(-SizeHalf,SizeHalf+1))
    part1=(x-GCenter[0])**2+(y-GCenter[1])**2
    GKernel = Gamp*np.exp(-0.5*Ggamma**-2*Gconst*part1)
    return GKernel

def conv2(x,y,mode='same'):
    """
    Emulate the Matlab function conv2 from Mathworks.

    Usage:
    z = conv2(x,y,mode='same')

    """

    if not(mode == 'same'):
        raise Exception("Mode not supported")

    # Add singleton dimensions
    if (len(x.shape) < len(y.shape)):
        dim = x.shape
        for i in range(len(x.shape),len(y.shape)):
            dim = (1,) + dim
        x = x.reshape(dim)
    elif (len(y.shape) < len(x.shape)):
        dim = y.shape
        for i in range(len(y.shape),len(x.shape)):
            dim = (1,) + dim
        y = y.reshape(dim)

    origin = ()

    # Apparently, the origin must be set in a special way to reproduce
    # the results of scipy.signal.convolve and Matlab
    for i in range(len(x.shape)):
        if ( (x.shape[i] - y.shape[i]) % 2 == 0 and
             x.shape[i] > 1 and
             y.shape[i] > 1):
            origin = origin + (-1,)
        else:
            origin = origin + (0,)

    z = convolve(x,y, mode='constant', origin=origin)

    return z

# Create white noise array
N=50 # Noise array dimension
A=10 # Noise amplitude
noise = np.random.rand(N,N)*A

# Gaussian Noise paramerers
GCenter=[0,0]
Gconst=1

# First gaussian filter
cutoff_f1 = 0.05 # < pi/10
gamma1 = 1/(2*np.pi*cutoff_f1) #minimum gamma == 0.5
Gamp1 = 1/(2*np.pi*gamma1)
filtr1 = Gaussian2D([0,0],Gamp1,gamma1,Gconst)
# Second gaussian filter
cutoff_f2 = 0.04 # < pi/10
gamma2 = 1/(2*np.pi*cutoff_f2) #minimum gamma == 0.5
Gamp2 = 1/(2*np.pi*gamma2)
filtr2 = Gaussian2D([0,0],Gamp2,gamma2,Gconst)

# Convolve filters with noise
noise_filtr1 = conv2(noise, filtr1, mode='same')
noise_filtr2 = conv2(noise, filtr2, mode='same')

# Difference of Gaussian Output
noise_out = noise_filtr1- noise_filtr2
```